# how can i get variables after login without using session in php?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I made a login system using php that is connected to MySQL database, how can i make it show the username after login, so it goes like on the main login screen -> database check -> success page. 
**Without using the session**
On this success page how can i show the username, that was registered?

Comment: your question lacks on information, db schema etc. too many possible answers.

Comment: The schema is called employee, where the login information (employee id, password) are stored, in addition to other information that I want to show in the success page such as (first name, middle name, and last name)

Comment: query the database, loop over results, use arrays assigned from objects, and *away you go!* ;-) This is one way of many, of course.

Comment: I want to query the database (on the third page) based on the value submitted on the first page .. querying using the variables and $_POST[ ] produced an empty page

Comment: show us your code. we can't guess what you have written up until now

Comment: The only way I think is to really use session. After login retrieve from Db the user credentials and load it into session variables and access it to other pages. If you really decide to not use php session, you need to create a check query function and load it to every page that you have. It will be messy and tedious not same as php session...

Comment: Why you don't want to use session? without session you can use cookies or pass the name after login using hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

So, you said:

> how can i show the username, that was registered?

In other word, you just need the username to be displayed by a correct password, whatever that user was really logged-in , right?

So the process is

**login screen -> submit -> save username in cookie -> DB check, password is correct -> fetch user full name and return as html**

**login screen -> submit -> save username in cookie -> DB check, password is wrong -> show error.**

I think this just fit you request :

> display the username

In fact, **The user is actually not in "logged-in" status, therefore, that user can do nothing as its identity**

If this is you first few homework in "web programming 101", you may save the username in cookie when login succeed. Then read the username value from Cookie to identify which user made the request. **But that's a nightmare for security, even a kid can hack your system**

If you just hate the build-in session of PHP, you may deploy your own session management tool. and in most case, it won't be more secure than the build-in one, when you are not experienced in cyber security.